# Performing regex queries with PyMongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to perform a regex query using PyMongo against a MongoDB server. The document structure is as follows

```
{
  "files": [
    "File 1",
    "File 2",
    "File 3",
    "File 4"
  ],
  "rootFolder": "/Location/Of/Files"
}
```

I want to get all the files that match the pattern *File. I tried doing this as such

```
db.collectionName.find({'files':'/^File/'})
```

Yet I get nothing back. Am I missing something, because according to the MongoDB docs this should be possible? If I perform the query in the Mongo console it works fine, does this mean the API doesn't support it or am I just using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Turns out regex searches are done a little differently in pymongo but is just as easy.

Regex is done as follows :

```
db.collectionname.find({'files':{'$regex':'^File'}})
```

This will match all documents that have a files property that has a item within that starts with File

Comment: Actually, what you have here is also the [way it's done in javascript](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/) (and probably other languages too) if you use `$regex`. @Eric's answer is the python way that's a little different.

Comment: what's the difference? They're both using python pymongo correct? It is part of mongodb queries so I don't see the issue really.

Comment: Ignorecase is possible in regex of mongodb JScript  also  viz. db.collectionname.find({'files':{'$regex':'^File','$options':'i'}})

Comment: This answer looks better to my eyes. Why bother compiling a Python RE if you're just going to stringify it so that Mongo can compile it again? Mongo's `$regex` operator takes an `$options` argument.

Comment: Please use `r'^File'` instead of `'^File'` to avoid other problem

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried to do what I thought would be a simple expansion of this to return all files starting with the letters A-F as follows

Comment: It's also worth noting that it's still possible to use variables in the regular expression when compiled this way: `db.collectionname.find({'files':{'$regex':'^{}'.format(myVar)}})`

Comment: someone answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49843914/how-to-return-documents-which-are-contains-the-specific-keywords-in-the-keys-fro?noredirect=1#comment86702821_49843914

Answer (score 213):

If you want to include regular expression options (such as ignore case), try this:

```
import re
regx = re.compile("^foo", re.IGNORECASE)
db.users.find_one({"files": regx})
```

Comment: Note also that regex's anchored at the start (ie: starting with `^`) are able to use indexes in the db, and will run much faster in that case.

Comment: Regex's starting with ^ can only use an index in [certain cases](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/). When using re.IGNORECASE I believe mongo can't use an index to perform the query.

Comment: Is this usage documented somewhere? I can't find this in the official pymongo API doc.

Answer (score 17):

To avoid the double compilation you can use the bson regex wrapper that comes with PyMongo:

```
>>> regx = bson.regex.Regex('^foo')
>>> db.users.find_one({"files": regx})
```

Regex just stores the string without trying to compile it, so find_one can then detect the argument as a 'Regex' type and form the appropriate Mongo query.

I feel this way is slightly more Pythonic than the other top answer, e.g.:

```
>>> db.collectionname.find({'files':{'$regex':'^File'}})
```

It's worth reading up on the bson Regex documentation if you plan to use regex queries because there are some caveats.

Comment: If you need to match agains an array using $in then $regex would not work for you. `bson.regex.Regex ` will do the trick!

Answer (score 9):

The solution of `re` doesn't use the index at all.
You should use commands like:

`db.collectionname.find({'files':{'$regex':'^File'}})`

( I cannot comment below their replies, so I reply here )