# How to implement regex expression that includes {m,n} in a mongodb query using pymongo?

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I would like to count documents with a certain amount of characters for one specific field, and I do this by using regex:

```
total_count = db.collection.count({'field': {'$regex': '^pattern{m,n}$'}})
```

This fails. 
The problem is in the `{m,n}` syntax for mongodb/pymongo, because the following gives good results:

```
total_count = db.collection.count({'field': {'$regex' : '^pattern+'}})
```

and the expression `'/^pattern{m,n}$/'` works smoothly in other applications (tested on: http://www.regexr.com/)

In my case, `pattern = [0-9a-zA-Z \W],` but this should not be relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile your regular expression pattern using [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.compile) function into a regular expression object

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'^pattern{n, m}$')
total_count = db.collection.count({'field': {'$regex': pat}})
```

Comment: wow thanks! That actually works. Though I find it surprising as I thought  mongodb had a regex compiler build in so I thought it would be unnecessary double/repeating.. I thougt recompiling upfront (in python) was only necessary in case of using 'options' of regex...Could you elaborate as to why your answer works?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483318/performing-regex-queries-with-pymongo

Comment: @annakeuchenius read the first comment to the accepted answer and the second answer.