# Usage of "$nin" in pymongo script

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am running a python script to retrieve data from a mongo collection. I would like to use the "$nin" operator to retrieve all the fields from the collection except for the ones whose "UserID" is not like "xyz.com". Below is my script, I am running into a syntax error using the script. Could you please let me know how the "$nin" should be represented in pymongo ?

```
for data in db.userauthorization.find({'UserID':{"$nin":{[/'xyz.com'/]}}}):
    print data
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The syntax error is not in the $nin, it's in the use of slashes around the regex.

Comment: Right, as such, this is basically a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483318/performing-regex-queries-with-pymongo

Answer (score 0):

Try without "/" 
for data in db.userauthorization.find({'UserID':{"$nin":{['xyz.com']}}}):
    print data