# how to search for a partial match text using mongodb or pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I've a document with a nested json data. It has 15 text and 10 integer datatypes.

How can I write a query such that any text or integer that matches should be displayed?

I tried the following query but it did not work as expected.

```
db.customers.find({ sno : /ab/ },{ name : /ab/ }).count()
```

I'm getting 0 count as result. I'm looking at OR clause and not AND clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify every field within a `$or` statement:

```
 db.customers.find({$or: [
     {field1: /ab/ },
     {field2: /ab/ },
     {field3: /ab/ },
     {field4: /ab/ },
     {field5: /ab/ }
 ]}).count()
```

You could also use a text query, for this you'll have to create a text index:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "$**": "text" } )
```

Then query it using:

```
db.articles.find( { $text: { $search: "ab" } } )
```

Text query - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/
Text index - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/

Comment: Thank You, Kevin for your response! How can I convert this query in pymongo ? I tried adding quotes and double quotes everywhere but did not get right response .

Comment: You need to create a regex, see this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/a/4877662/4079967