# How to write this MongoDB query in a valid way?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have this MongoDB query in Python.

```
    results = collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "monitor": {
                "$in": [/\/tcp/,/\/http$/,/\/https_443$/,/\/https$/,/\/http_head_f5$/,/\/https_head_f5$/,/\/icmp$/]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "name": 1,
            "partition": 1,
            "fullPath": 1,
            "type": 1,
            "loadBalancingMode": 1,
            "monitor": 1,
            "f5ip": 1,
            "poolstatus": 1
        }}
])
```

I am having difficulty turning this line into a valid Python syntax

```
"$in": [/\/tcp/,/\/http$/,/\/https_443$/,/\/https$/,/\/http_head_f5$/,/\/https_head_f5$/,/\/icmp$/]
```

I tried "$regex" option but we cannot use $regex inside $in. 
I also tried converting the array elements into the string and escaping the slashes as shown below.

```
"$in": ["\/\/tcp\/","\/\/http$/"]
```

I want to know how I can turn that MongoDB query into valid python syntax and receive the same results using PyMongo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Performing regex Queries with pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483318/performing-regex-queries-with-pymongo)

Comment: Thanks, it did not help but it pointed me in the right direction. See below.

Answer (score 0):

I converted the array as shown below

```
options = ['tcp', 'http$', 'https_443$', 'https$', 'http_head_f5$', 'https_head_f5$', 'icmp$']
regex_options = []

for option in options:
    pattern = re.compile(option)
    regex = bson.regex.Regex.from_native(pattern)
    regex_options.append(regex)

results = collection.aggregate([
{
    "$match": {
        "monitor": {
            "$in": regex_options
        }
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "name": 1,
        "partition": 1,
        "fullPath": 1,
        "type": 1,
        "loadBalancingMode": 1,
        "monitor": 1,
        "f5ip": 1,
        "poolstatus": 1
    }}
])
```

Reference : [regex – Tools for representing MongoDB regular expressions¶](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/regex.html#bson.regex.Regex.try_compile)

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to to use an aggregate query, but either way this construct should work:

```
results= db.collection.find({'monitor': {'$regex': 'tcp|http$|https_443$|https$|http_head_f5$|https_head_f5$|icmp$'}},
                            {'_id': 0, 'name': 1, 'partition': 1, 'fullPath': 1, 'type': 1, 'loadBalancingMode': 1,
                             'monitor': 1, 'f5ip': 1, 'poolstatus': 1})
```