# pymongo query regex

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to retrieve all stories where the images.path has the text "images123456.jpg" for example.

In my mongocompass, I am able to retrieve it using this

```
{$and: [{"images.path": {$exists: true}}, {"images.path": /.*images[1-9].*/}] }
```

In my python script, I tried to paste the query in the following.

```
client = MongoClient(HOST, PORT)
dbStuff = client['myDatabase']   
myCollection = dbStuff.story.with_options(codec_options=CodecOptions(tz_aware=True, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('Asia/Singapore'))) 
retrieved = myCollection .find({"$and": [{"images.path": {"$exists": True}}, {"images.path": '/.*images[1-9].*/'}] })
print retrieved.count() # Prints out 0
```

There is something wrong in the python script for

```
{"images.path": '/.*images[1-9].*/'}] }
```

part. How can i make the necessary changes?

Comment: I found the same question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483318/performing-regex-queries-with-pymongo

Comment: It is explained in PyMongo [docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/bson/regex.html)

Comment: try this, ```myCollection.find({"$and": [{"images.path": {"$exists": True}}, {"images.path": {'$regex': '.*images[1-9].*'}}]})```

Answer (score 0):

`/` is used as regular expression delimiter in some languages like JS. In Python you just write the contents of a regular expression as a string.

JS: `/foo.*bar/`

Python: `r'foo.*bar'`